# How to do some Combat Runs when starting out as a Humble Trader?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

So I just started playing X<sup>3</sup>: Terran Conflict and decided to start out as a Humble Merchant.

I get dropped out in space. nice!

I notice the Argon Flight School Buster; a flight school, how very nice!

I learn how to control my ship, dock and undock at a station, and now it is time for some combat runs.

Our lovely instructor has dropped some Debris for me to shoot down, and I proceed to move towards it, target it and trying to shoot it, only to have nothing happening.

I check my ship again, and notice there is totally no weaponry installed. NOT NICE!

So, where can I get my first weapon so i can continue learning how to control my ship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't.  While you do start with an additional M5 (check your ship list to find it) and you have the option to sell that at a shipyard to buy some weapons, your reputation with the Argons will probably not be high enough to be able to even purchase an impulse ray emitter.

IMO, just ignore the flight instructor and go exploring, he doesn't give you a reward for finishing his flight training anyway :)

For a beginner, the best recommended start IMO is actually the Terran start.  You get a pretty good M4 with high speed, and you get several EMPCs, which can pack a punch when fired as a cluster.

Play through the game for a few hours in that start to get the hang of it, then revisit your humble merchant.

However, if you wish to stick with your start, there are usually some space fuel distilleries in the sector north of argon prime that you can buy (they are fully stocked at the start of the game), and sell to the nearby trading station for some quick profit.  Just beware that its illegal and if the police scan you, you might be in trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I did some runs of Space Fuel, staying inside the system, and switched to ore and energy while hesistantly exploring the surrounding area afterwards. starting with X3TC isn't that hard if you've played loads of freelancer (multiplayer) and a trial of EVE Online.